# L/100 km or km/L? which one is used? I am planning travel in Mexico & Colombia by car

Tags: india, automobiles, mexico, local-customs, colombia

In America we say the fuel economy of car in miles/gallon. I know in k countries people use liters/100 km. Some countries use km/liter.

My question is: Which format is used in Mexico, Colombia, and India, L/100 km or km/L?

Comment: Got answer about Mexico. How about India?

Comment: Is there an end goal related to travel for your question?

Comment: Hi and welcome. I fail to see the travel aspect of this question. Are you planning a road trip across these countries? Or are you just planning to buy a car there?

Comment: A calculator or google can quickly convert one to another. If any of the conversion pairs involves gallons, make sure you are using the correct type of gallons (US gallons are considerably smaller than Imperial gallons).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick look at some Mexican auto dealers' web sites shows them using km/L. Examples: [1](http://soloautos.mx/usados/auto/volkswagen-passat_cc-2012-moka/1033896) [2](http://www.autocosmos.com.mx/catalogo/vigente/chevrolet/camaro/rs-v6-aut/160596)

Comment: There's not much difference between a litre and a Litre...

Comment: So I can say 10 km/L or 10 km/l. Both are correct?

Comment: @Tony Yes, [L and l both mean litre](http://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/si_brochure_8_en.pdf).

Comment: It is km/l in India as well. 

Source: I'm an Indian :)

Comment: @MichaelHampton Abbreviations for physical units and SI prefixes are indeed case sensitive. mg, Mg, mG and MG are four different things.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: Yes, in general. But the liter _in particular_ has two symbols to choose between. The BIPM's [SI brochure says](http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/table6.html) "The litre, and the symbol lower-case l, were adopted by the CIPM in 1879 (PV, 1879, 41). The alternative symbol, capital L, was adopted by the 16th CGPM (1979, Resolution 6) in order to avoid the risk of confusion between the letter l (el) and the numeral 1 (one)."

Comment: Interesting to know ' liter in particular has two symbols to choose between.'

Answer (score 2):

In Colombia Km/[US](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gal%C3%B3n) Gallon is used.

Source: http://www.carroya.com/contenido/clasificar/Chicas_famosos/top_carroya/20111/ARTICULO-WEB-PTL_NOTA-9968965.html (in spanish).

Comment: What sort of gallons? Imperial gallons or US gallons?

Comment: on this link it says  52 mpg (22 km/l). Does not look like Km/Gallon is used. http://noticias.autocosmos.com.co/2016/02/17/toyota-prius-2016-by-wald-international-ecologia-deportiva

Comment: @vclaw don't really know, we use gallons in gas stations, but really don't know.

Comment: @Tony I don't know about that webpage, but I'm pretty sure we use Km/Gallon. Check this article instead: http://www.carroya.com/contenido/clasificar/Chicas_famosos/top_carroya/20111/ARTICULO-WEB-PTL_NOTA-9968965.html